# Lapply on columns of a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames that looks like this:

$`0`

```
            My_Patient_Name   Control       My_experiment
              Patient1         <NA>             <NA>    
              Patient2         <NA>             <NA>
              Patient3         <NA>             YES
```

$`1`

```
            My_Patient_Name   Control       My_experiment
              Patient4         1,3,5             <NA>    
              Patient5         1,3,5             <NA>
              Patient6         1,3,5             <NA>
```

I would like to check if in each data.frame of the list there are NA in the column Control. For one data.frame at a time it is:

```
 condition = sapply(mydf[[1]][2],function(x) {!all(is.na(x))}
 then    

 condition = sapply(mydf[[2]][2],function(x) {!all(is.na(x))}
 and so on.
```

But I would like to run it on each data.frame of the list.

Comment: Please provide sample data/a reproducible example. For example, use dput() on 2-3 of your dataframes, or construct 2-3 brief sample dfs we can copy & run ourselves to troubleshoot.

Comment: Note: There is also an `any` function that gives TRUE if any of the values are TRUE and FALSE otherwise.  That way you don't have to play around with negating the result from `all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lapply to check your condition on each element of the list

```
mydf = list()
mydf[[1]] <- data.frame(My_Patient_Name=c("Patient1", "Patient2", "Patient3"), Control=c(NA, NA, NA), My_experiment=c(NA,NA,"YES"))
mydf[[2]] <- data.frame(My_Patient_Name=c("Patient3", "Patient4", "Patient5"), Control=c("1,3,5", "1,3,5", "1,3,5"), My_experiment=c(NA,NA,NA))
lapply(mydf, function(df) sapply(df[2],function(x) {any(is.na(x))}))
#[[1]]
#Control 
#    TRUE 

#[[2]]
#Control 
#    FALSE
```